# How to change umask for a files created by application

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm using Fatrat (http://fatrat.dolezel.info/) on a headless server. I would like every file and folder it creates (downloads) to be set with permissions umask 770 , so I can delete it via Samba user which is in the same group as the user that runs the Fatrat application

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `umask` command to set the umask before executing Fatrat. `umask` only changes the `umask` for the current shell and any commands started from it, so if you are launching Fatrat from a shortcut or window manager keybinding try using `sh -c "umask $YOUR_NEW_UMASK; exec fatrat"` as the command.

Comment: I'm launching Fatrat as a headless service on Arch Linux: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/fatrat -n` and `Type=simple`. So should I change run the service in one-line: `ExecStart=sh -c "umask 007; exec /usr/bin/fatrat -n"` or split it to two ExecStart lines?

Comment: Yes, do it as one line. You actually cannot have multiple ExecStart lines unless the type is `oneshot` (which isn't what you want here).

Comment: OK, so if anyone else stumbled upon this, the solution for `rwxrwx---` is: `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "umask 007 ; /usr/bin/fatrat -n"` (drop "exec" from previous versions)

Comment: The exec will get rid of the no longer needed shell process. Did it not work with exec?

Comment: Yes it did not work - some problem with parameters.